# Ignore to load XML file from SpringBootApplication

Tags: spring-boot, spring-boot-test

I have a Spring Boot application structure like this:

```
src/main/java
            /main/Application.java
src/main/resource/
            /application-context.xml
src/test/java
            /main/TestApplication.java          
src/test/resource/
            /application-context-test.xml
```

When I start application by `Run As Spring Boot Application` or `Run as Junit`
Both `application-context.xml` and `application-context-test.xml` were loaded.

But I only want to load `application-context.xml` in running mode, and `application-context-test.xml` in testing mode.

The initialisers look like:

```
@ImportResource("classpath:application-context.xml")
public class Application{

  public static void main(String[] args) {
    SpringApplication.run(Application.class, args);
  }

}


@ImportResource("classpath:application-context-test.xml")
public class TestApplication{

  public static void main(String[] args) {
    SpringApplication.run(TestApplication.class, args);
  }

}
```

but they do not work.
Both the XMLs are loaded. How can I resolve this?

Answer (score 0):

Annotate TestApplication with :

```
@RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)
@SpringApplicationConfiguration(classes = TestApplication.class)
```

Comment: Thanks, I was use `@SpringBootTest(classes = TestApplication.class)` because `SpringApplicationConfiguration` is deprecated but it still not work